# Can't insert date into elasticsearch due to mapper_parsing_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am inserting data to elasticsearch:

```rb
client.index(index: "dev_index", id: 123, body: {"test_date": "2019-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

using the mappings in the format below:

```json
{
  "mappings":{
    "dynamic":false,
    "properties":{
      "test_date":{
        "type":"date",
        "format":"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I am seeing the below error when I try to insert data:

```json
{
  "error":{
    "root_cause":[
      {
        "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason":"failed to parse field [test_date] of type [date] in document with id '1234'. Preview of field's value: '2019-01-01 00:00:00'"
      }
    ],
    "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason":"failed to parse field [test_date] of type [date] in document with id '1234'. Preview of field's value: '2019-01-01 00:00:00'",
    "caused_by":{
      "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason":"failed to parse date field [2019-01-01 00:00:00] with format [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]",
      "caused_by":{
        "type":"date_time_parse_exception",
        "reason":"Text '2019-01-01 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 14"
      }
    }
  },
  "status":400
```

What am I doing wrong here? Index 14 seems to be referring to the minutes but I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Don't you have to use `MM` instead of `mm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have mentioned the date format incorrectly in your mapping. It should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" (uppercase M for Months)

In your Mapping you have mentioned 'mm' for Months as well as minutes. Correct your mapping as below:

{
"mappings":{
"dynamic":false,
"properties":{
"test_date":{
"type":"date",
"format":"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
}
}
}
}